# Why did Naruto act like he never heard Hinata's first love confession that happened during Pain's assault?

Tags: naruto

During Pain's assault to Konoha, Hinata risked her life for Naruto and confessed her love for him. But after that, Naruto behaves as if that situation never happened. Later Hinata is nervous to have to confess to him a second time, and in any situation Hinata was nervous for being around Naruto due to being in love with him, he was completely disconnected from it.

Why did Naruto act like he never heard Hinata's first love confession that happened during Pain's assault?

Answer (score 4):

Because he was in love with Sakura back then. So when Hinata confessed during Pain's assault, he thought she loved him because she's a **comrade**, a leaf shinobi who doesn't let his/her comrade die. Naruto actually took it as a friend.

Later fighting against Madara & Tobi/Obito, there are flashbacks (when Neji dies) where the dialogue goes "My friends are ready to give up their lives for me" and the flashback of Hinata being stabbed by Pain.